# Global Random Bits from Nature

Tags: solar-system, cosmic-rays, randomness

I would like to get a few random bits per day from nature (from chaotic physics, like rolling
dice, or quantum physics, but not from cryptography) which Alice and Bob can measure
independently from opposite sides of the USA.  My first instinct is to
measure emissions from the sun, or even other stars, but I have no idea what
exact emission has strong variation and strong correlation across the earth.
I'm aware of all the NASA satellite data, which could be used, but
I'd prefer something with "theoretical flip-flop bistability".  Does
the galaxy flip any coins?

What's a practical (preferably cheap) recommendation?  Does anyone already
do this?

Comment: You mentioned Alice and Bob. That means you are interested in entanglement. What is your goal? Are you doing some project, or trying to investigate reality of entanglement?

Comment: Actually, Alice and Bob came from the cryptographic method.  But, here my goal is a method where Alice and Bob don't need to speak.  I am not interested in entanglement here.

Comment: How about counting or observing the position of solar flares>